# Write recorded browser action in a file through Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I know that with Selenium we can record browser actions and can save them as a video file. Is there any way I can use Selenium to record browser actions and write recorded steps in a file (notepad/excel)?

Basically a file that has a list of actions performed by the user on different HTML elements.

For example:

- Go to {url}
- Click on {id of the control}

Comment: this is how Selenium used to work.  Not sure if it's still supported, but you could use the earlier versions which worked as browser plugins.

Comment: I realized Selenium browser plugin only captures events. It does not record navigation that users do with pressing Tab. I need to record that as well.